# Sequelize migrations for CockroachDB - ERROR: no data source matches prefix: ranges

Tags: migration, sequelize.js, cockroachdb

I using https://github.com/tomyitav/apollo-typed-lambda as a boiler plate for my GraphQL.
Behind GraphQL I want to use CockraochDB.

Installed sequelize, sequelize-cli, sequelize-cockroachdb

```
npm install sequelize pg pg-hstore
npm install sequelize sequelize-cockroachdb
npm install sequelize-cli
```

sequelize configured for cockroachDB connection.

After that created a simple migration

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Todos', {

      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      complete: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
      }

    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Todos');
  }
};
```

When I run this migration it gives me following error msg

> ERROR: no data source matches prefix: ranges

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your cockroacdhdb to 19.2.1 would solve this problem. It's cockroachdb's bug pertaining to `Common Table Expressions`.

Answer (score 0):

I inspect the source code of sequelize. All I know is sequelize trys to construct a `with subquery statement`  internally which is not supported by CockroachDB's engine.

```js
return (connection || this.sequelize).query(
      'WITH ranges AS (' +
      '  SELECT pg_range.rngtypid, pg_type.typname AS rngtypname,' +
      '         pg_type.typarray AS rngtyparray, pg_range.rngsubtype' +
      '    FROM pg_range LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_type ON pg_type.oid = pg_range.rngtypid' +
      ')' +
      'SELECT pg_type.typname, pg_type.typtype, pg_type.oid, pg_type.typarray,' +
      '       ranges.rngtypname, ranges.rngtypid, ranges.rngtyparray' +
      '  FROM pg_type LEFT OUTER JOIN ranges ON pg_type.oid = ranges.rngsubtype' +
      ' WHERE (pg_type.typtype IN(\'b\', \'e\'));'
    )
```

Comment: Could you please add a description to your answer about how and why the code snippet you've provided solves the problem? In other words: what is the root cause of the problem here, and how does your code snippet solve that? - Adding examples would be good to underestand the solution.